# 2sxc Content.Toolbar add existing item to list

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

The Content.Toolbar offers a number of options for list management.  The one option that I can't find is "add existing content item to list.

If you've defined a demo content item for the list, that will be added and you can then replace it, but I find that to be a pain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't exist. If you think it's a valuable add-on, post a request on github.